# Can't disable Night light in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, nightlight

I can't disable Windows 10 Night Light, I have tried all solutions that I can found and nothing helps me. The only thing helps me - killing process dwm.exe, then night light disabled until display goes to suspend mode.

Video: Intel UHD Graphics 630

OS: Windows 10 21H1 19043.1706

Things I've tried:

- Different registry tweaks (for ex. https://allthings.how/windows-10-night-light-wont-turn-off-heres-a-fix/)
- Uninstalling video driver (installing then from Windows Update and from Intel site)
- sfc /scannow
- DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

I don't want to reinstall OS, please give me any ideas to fix it.

Comment: DISM / SFC did not work. Try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link. Keep Everything and see if that works.

Comment: What does *Settings > System > Display* say for "Night light"? And the same for it in Action Center? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc button don't work, it always turned on when night light enabled and turning it off doing nothing

Comment: And in Action Center? See also if it happens when booting in Safe mode.

Comment: @harrymc same thing - button don't work. I'll try safe mode and post later

Comment: Is this machine connected to a AD domain.  Please [edit] your question instead of replying to this comment

Comment: Did you just remove the driver from the device manager? Removing it in safe mode by using DDU (Display Driver Uninstaller) might be a better option. Media Creation Tool like John mentioned is also a good suggestion. I've had much more success with it than with either DISM or SFC.

Comment: John posted a perfect solution above, reinstalling OS from Media Creation Tool helped me. @John please, post this comment as answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't disable Windows 10 Night Light .... [tried] ...     sfc
> /scannow,     DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

DISM / SFC did not work.

The (normally) best solution after DISM/SFC is  a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link. Keep Everything and see if that works.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally
> answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything

Answer (score 0):

1. Try changing and saving *Night light* settings *both* logged in as a normal user and logged in as Administrator.
2. Check that [Group Policy allows setting *Night light*.](https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/nightlight-missing-from-action-center-in-windows-10.601397/)
3. As a work-around, change the *time* *Night light* is active to just 15 minutes. Do this as both user and Admin.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type *Night light* in *Search*.
- Select the *Nightlight* CPL and turn it *On*.
- Select convenient times 15 minutes apart.
- You can also set the *Strength* slider to the minimum setting.

[image: Night light CPL]